# Question about Doob's decomposition and a theorem in Durrett

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $X_n$ be a martingale with $X_0 = 0$ and $EX_n^2<\infty$ for all n. $X_n^2$ is a submartingale and thus $X_n^2 = M_n + A_n$.

I don't understand a step in this theorem: $E(\text{sup}_n |X_n|)\leq 3EA_{\infty}^{1/2}$, where $A_{\infty}=\text{lim}_n A_n$.

Proof: Let $a>0$ and let $N = \text{inf}\{n:A_{n+1}>a^2\}$, then

$$P(\text{sup}_n |X_n|>a)\leq P(N<\infty)+ P(\text{sup}_n |X_{n\wedge N}|>a)$$

I don't understand why {$\text{sup}_n |X_n|>a\} \implies \{N<\infty\}$? Thanks.

Comment: If $X_n$ is a constant sequence, then so is $X_n^2$, and thus $X_n^2=M_n$ and $A_n=0$...

Comment: Doesn't that violate $EA_n = EX_n^2$?

Comment: But if $(X_n)$ is constante sequence (i.e. for example $\mathbb P\{X_n=2\}=1$ for all $n$), then so is $X_n^2$ right ? So you have that $X_{n-1}^2=4=\mathbb E[X_n^2\mid \mathcal F_{n-1}]$ (may be I misunderstood your question)...

Comment: You're right, $X_n^2$ is also a constant sequence and hence a martingale and thus $A_n = 0$. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality follows from the inclusion $(\sup_n |X_n|>a) \subset (N<\infty) \cup (\text{sup}_n |X_{n\wedge N}|>a)$.

That's because $\begin{aligned}[t](\sup_n |X_n|>a) 
&= [(\sup_n |X_n|>a)\cap (N<\infty)]\cup [(\sup_n |X_n|>a)\cap (N=\infty)]\\
&=[(\sup_n |X_n|>a)\cap (N<\infty)]\cup [(\sup_n |X_{n\wedge N}|>a)\cap (N=\infty)]\\
&\subset (N<\infty) \cup (\sup_n |X_{n\wedge N}|>a)
\end{aligned}$

The union bound then yields $$P(\sup_n |X_n|>a) \leq P(N<\infty) + (\sup_n |X_{n\wedge N}|>a)$$